# Sort array2 following the order in array1

Tags: perl

I have two arrays `@ar1` and `@ar2`.

```
my @ar1 = qw( 10 100 80 70 40 50 90 110 );
```

`@ar1` is not sorted but the same order is to be followed by `@ar2`.

Some of the elements in `@ar2` are not found in `@ar1` and vice versa

```
my @ar2 = qw( 100 40 50 70 30 80 10 );
```

I need to sort `@ar2` based on the `@ar1` order. If an `@ar2` element is not found in `@ar1` then put it in the last `@ar2`.

Expected output:

```
@ar2 = qw/ 10 100 80 70 40 50 30 /
```

Here `30` is not found in `@ar1` we put it last

Here is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "";
my @ar3 = ();

for my $sn ( @ar1 ) {

    if ( grep /$sn/, @ar2 ) {

        push @ar3, $sn;
        shift @ar2, $sn;
    }
}

print @ar3;

print "\n";

print @ar2;
```

I would appreciate it someone can offer me a solution.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Please find the expected output and revisit. In my question `@ar2` is the same thing in the expected output `@ar2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do 2 for loops, the first one to find numbers that are in `@ar1` and `@ar2` and the second to find numbers that are in `@ar2` but not in `@ar1`:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my @ar1 = qw( 10 100 80 70 40 50 90 110); 
my @ar2 = qw( 100 40 50 70 30 80 10);
my @ar3 = ();

foreach my $sn(@ar1) {
    push @ar3, $sn if grep {$_ == $sn} @ar2;
}
foreach my $sn(@ar2) {
    next if grep {$_ == $sn} @ar1;
    next if grep {$_ == $sn} @ar3;
    push @ar3, $sn;
}
say"@ar3";
```

**Output:**

```
10 100 80 70 40 50 30
```

Comment: Awesome. This is what I expected. I realized where I did mistake in my code.

Comment: *"You have to do 2 for loops"* No.

Comment: This solution scales very poorly. (See my answer for details.) And all those regex matches are going to make things extremely slow! It's also much more complex than needed. Avoid this solution!!!!

Comment: @ikegami:Thanks for edit, OK for anchors but is escaping `\Q...\E` usefull here as we deal with integers only? And, sure, your solution runs quicker than mine, but for small arrays as given by OP, it doesn't make significant  differences.

Comment: You're the only that assumed that they weren't integers. If we assume they're just integers, you should use `$_ ==  $sn` instead of `/^\Q$sn\E\z/`. // Your right about speed. For the OP's imputs, yours: 0.11ms, mine: 0.01ms. So even though mine is 10x faster, the numbers are so small numbers that it doesn't matter unless it's done often. But that changes drastically as the arrays grow. Just doubling the size of the array makes mine 20x faster than yours. // Aside from speed, your code's flow is much more complicated, and is thus harder to follow. That's the primary reason it should be avoided.

Comment: @ikegami:I agree with you, but, I've just reuse OP's code and it works for her/him

Comment: It doesn't, actually. Imagine if `@ar1` contains `1` and `@ar2` contains `10`.

Comment: @ikegami: I talked about my code that works (may be slowly) for her/him.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a hash that pairs each value in `@ar1` with its corresponding index into the array, then you can simply write a `sort` subroutine that compares the *indexes* of the two values if they both appear in the hash, or ranks non-existent values higher than anything else to put them at the end

It looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my @ar1 = qw( 10 100 80 70 40 50 90 110 );

my @ar2 = qw( 100 40 50 70 30 80 10 );

my %rank = map { $ar1[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#ar1;

my @sorted = sort sort_by_ar1 @ar2;

sub sort_by_ar1 {

    my ($aa, $bb) = map $rank{$_}, $a, $b;

    if ( defined $aa ) {

        # If they're both defined then compare them
        # Else if only $aa is defined then $bb is greater

        return defined $bb ? $aa <=> $bb : -1;
    }
    else {

        # If only $bb is defined then $aa is greater
        # Else they are both undefined and are nominally equal

        return defined $bb ? 1 : 0;
    }
}


dd \@ar1;
dd \@ar2;
dd [ 'Sorted:', @sorted ];
```

#### output

```
[10, 100, 80, 70, 40, 50, 90, 110]
[100, 40, 50, 70, 30, 80, 10]
["Sorted:", 10, 100, 80, 70, 40, 50, 30]
```

Comment: That simplifies to: `@ar2 = sort { ( $rank{$a} // keys(%rank) ) <=> ( $rank{$b} // keys(%rank) ) } @ar2;`. It scales better than Toto's, but not as well as mine.

Answer (score 1):

Toto was right about just needing a loop to find the numbers that are in both `@ar1` and `@ar2`, plus a second loop to find the numbers that are in `@ar2` but not in `@ar1`. However, their implementation was abysmal. The following is a far more efficient implementation:

```
my %ar1 = map { $_ => 1 } @ar1;
my %ar2 = map { $_ => 1 } @ar2;

@ar2 = ( grep($ar2{$_}, @ar1), grep(!$ar1{$_}, @ar2) );
```

---

Performance analysis:
(N = number of elements in @ar2,
M = number of elements in @ar1)

ikegami: O(N + M)
Borodin: O(N log N + M)
Toto: O(N*M)

This means that Toto's solution scales very very poorly compared to the alternatives, with mine scaling the best.

Comment: If anyone has problems dealing with two vars in the performance analysis, assume the size of `@ar1` and `@ar2` grow proportionally. This simplifies the analysis to the following: ikegami-O(N), Borodin-O(N log N) and Toto-O(N^2).