# What general approaches exist in excel to reorder/reshuffle array2 to match the order of array1?

Tags: excel, vba

I see there is [this solution for pearl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393493/sort-array2-following-the-order-in-array1) which is in-line with what I am thinking. I could use intersect or something similar; however, I am looking to do it in VBA and would ideally reshuffle the arrays so that there is **visual clarity** on which elements are missing from either of the arrays. I should mention that I am interested in finding out all discrepancies between both arrays.

In my case one of the arrays is usually longer than the other one and sometimes they contain entries that aren't in one of them. I would like to take arr2 and reshuffle/map it to arr1 like this:
*@Blackcat has brought to my attention that I haven't made my inquiry clear so I am providing a second example:

**either of the arrays can have missing values from the opposing array; I want to sort on each row the corresponding values or if missing leave a blank

Example 1:
[image: example1]

Example 2 /why sorting both arrays doesn't work for me/:
[image]

Currently I have this GPT written code which is kinda functional but I can't exactly troubleshoot because I can't figure out when it breaks and the dataset I'm using it on is quite big:

```
Sub ReshuffleTablesBigTest()
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("bigtest")
        
    Dim lastRowTable1 As Long
    lastRowTable1 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim lastRowTable2 As Long
    lastRowTable2 = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim table1 As Range
    Set table1 = ws.Range("A1:E" & lastRowTable1)
    
    Dim table2 As Range
    Set table2 = ws.Range("H1:L" & lastRowTable2)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim matchedRows As New Collection
    
    For i = 1 To table1.Rows.Count
        Dim key As String
        key = table1.Cells(i, 1).Value & "|" & table1.Cells(i, 2).Value & "|" & table1.Cells(i, 3).Value & "|" & table1.Cells(i, 4).Value & "|" & table1.Cells(i, 5).Value
     
        Dim j As Long
        Dim matchFound As Boolean
        matchFound = False
     
        For j = 1 To table2.Rows.Count
            Dim rowKey As String
            rowKey = table2.Cells(j, 1).Value & "|" & table2.Cells(j, 2).Value & "|" & table2.Cells(j, 3).Value & "|" & table2.Cells(j, 4).Value & "|" & table2.Cells(j, 5).Value
         
            If rowKey = key And Not Contains(matchedRows, j) Then
                table2.Rows(j).Cut
                table2.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                matchedRows.Add j ' Mark the row as matched
                matchFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
     
        If Not matchFound Then
            ' If a row from table1 is missing in table2, insert an empty row at the corresponding position in table2
            table2.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Function Contains(col As Collection, item As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    col.Add item, CStr(item)
    Contains = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Sort for Column B and after it Column A is available in Excel without vba. What is the sence of Array 1? The Sort method is available in VBA also.

Comment: Furthermore do you mean instead `sometimes they contain entries that aren't in either of them.` this  `that aren't in one of them.`

Comment: @Blackcat indeed; I like your sorting idea its just that sorting arr1 and then sorting arr2 its just that because both arrays contain strings that aren't in the other one, the rows would get displaced and I would lose visual clarity. I am interested in finding out all discrepancies between both arrays

Comment: This looks like a classic "gaps & islands" problem - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010653/excel-formula-or-vba-identifying-gaps-in-overlapping-dates-and-times

Comment: Your first example than not correct. Array 2 already contains the missing values from Array 1.

Comment: @Blackcat either of the arrays can have missing values from the opposing array; I want to sort on each row the corresponding values or if missing leave a blank

Comment: How does your first example provide visual clarity as to the items in Array1 that are not in Array2? Your result seems to be merely a sorted Array2.

Comment: And if you just want a list of items in one array that are not in the other, that would be relatively simple using either formulas (if you have `365`), VBA or Power Query.

Comment: Your `Contains` function tests to see if a Collection has an item with a specific key, but if the key *doesn't* already exist then it successfully adds that as a new item/key combo.  Shouldn't you then remove that added item?